Software for integration of the Everthing Search into the Windows Start Menu search
Looking for a software that can integrate Voidtools Everything Search into the Windows Start Menu, replacing the default start menu search. Preferably with a good-looking interface.

The EverythingToolbar works perfectly for that. It can have its own button at the task bar OR replace the default Windows Search. You just need to go to "preferences > replace task bar search". As a plus it is a free open-source piece of software.

